# iTunes 9.2 OS X - iTunes DJ not functioning correctly

Tags: macos, itunes

I have been using iTunes on my Mac for 4 years now without any problems at all. Recently, however, the iTunes DJ function has started misbehaving.

Instead of showing the 5 previously played songs, and 15 upcoming songs randomly selected from the playlist I have defined in the settings, it instead shows the 5 previously played songs, plus many more than 15 upcoming songs. In addition, the upcoming songs are not from the playlist, they are from about 7 or so albums, in album order.

I have changed settings, change the source playlist, restarted iTunes, rebooted the machine. All with no change.

Does anybody have any idea how to get this working again?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it doesn't matter anymore, but perhaps you accidentally highlighted a group of albums and selected "Add to iTunes DJ"?  This adds them to the iTunes DJ playlist even beyond the 15 song limit.

Comment: Stephen, thanks for the answer. You are right, it doesn't matter anymore. The library has been rebuilt at least once, and I have a new machine as well. It works as expected on it. I never did find out the problem. But I will keep your answer in mind should it ever come up again.

Answer (score 1):

Go to iTunes DJ, select all songs and delete the songs, they only are deleted from the playlist and not from your machine.

After that, refresh it, iTunes DJ will work normally.

Comment: Sandeep, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I long ago rebuilt my iTunes library, which fixed the problem. If it happens again, I will keep your answer in mind.